# Replace regex characters

Tags: java, regex, substring

I want to replace the substring `\\d+-\\d+` to a random genarated number in this String `<!-- This is Siebel Order identified --> <tns:id> <tns:idValue>\\d+-\\d+</tns:idValue`.

I am using the code below

```
String REGEXSIEBEL = "<!-- This is Siebel Order identified --> <tns:id> <tns:idValue>\\d+-\\d+</tns:idValue>";
java.util.regex.Pattern p1 = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(REGEXSIEBEL);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p1.matcher(INPUT);

INPUT = m.replaceAll(REGEXSIEBEL.replaceAll(String.valueOf("\\d+-\\d+"), String.valueOf(randomInt)));
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your regexes fast online using http://regex101.com/ and maybe you can also check this tutorial on java regexes for further reference : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Below you have a full implementation of your task at hand:

```
String str = "<!-- This is Siebel Order identified --> <tns:id> <tns:idValue>84678468-00</tns:idValue>";
String patternString = "<!-- This is Siebel Order identified --> <tns:id> <tns:idValue>\\d{8}-00<\\/tns:idValue>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while(matcher.find()){
   String randomNumberTag = "<!-- This is Siebel Order identified --> <tns:id> <tns:idValue>"+
        Integer.toString((int)(Math.random() * 99999999))
        +"-00</tns:idValue>";
   matcher.appendReplacement(sb,randomNumberTag);
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
```

**Update**
The previous code was meant to replace each occurence with a different random number, if you want all the occurences to be replaced with THE SAME random number use this:

```
String str = "<!-- This is Siebel Order identified --> <tns:id> <tns:idValue>84678468-00</tns:idValue>";
String patternString = "<!-- This is Siebel Order identified --> <tns:id> <tns:idValue>\\d{8}-00<\\/tns:idValue>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

String randomNumberTag = "<!-- This is Siebel Order identified --> <tns:id> <tns:idValue>"+
    Integer.toString((int)(Math.random() * 99999999))
            +"-00</tns:idValue>";
System.out.println(randomNumberTag);
if(matcher.find()){
    str = matcher.replaceAll(randomNumberTag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**`Matcher#ewplaceAll(String replacement)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\d+-\\d+");
Matcher m = p1.matcher(INPUT);
INPUT = m.replaceAll( String.valueOf(randomInt) );
```